# Unity colliders behave in a weird and unexpected way. How to solve that?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, collider

Ok so I know it's me and not the collider that is not working but I just don't understand why. In this clip you can see me moving my mouse over the enemy ship. I continuously click, and the onClick event makes the border around the enemy ship appear: https://gyazo.com/c1379139f0fe3d22ff510a0a1b45ab96 The hitbox is just a square around the entire ship so I was inside that all the time. After I managed to click on it I can shoot it but the cannonball just goes through it: https://gyazo.com/1914faecabe9c9a36cc1f5dc2632184c Here you can also see that the ball collides with the island as it should. I can also move the enemy ship with my own ship no problem.
The only thing every enemy has in common with this bug is it ONLY happens when the ship is close to an island.
If anyone could help solving that issue Id be really glad I have run completely out of ideas :(

Comment: Asking Unity related questions on SO is hard. But without any of the relevant code and/or editor settings it is literally impossible for anyone to help you. 
There could be a bug in the script that handles the cannonball collisions. There could be an issue with the object layers (Is the cannonball on the correct layer? Does the script include that layer when calculating the collisions?)
There could be something really obvious, that we just can't *see* because we can't *see* your editor.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in another project. Focus on only the parts that you want to test. Either you'll have found the problem by the end, or you'll have some short snippets of code or editor settings that you could share with us without dumping a wall of code on us.

Comment: I assume that it is on the right layer since it works on every ship that is not near an island, the collision logic on the ball just checks if it left the players collider, and if the next collider it enters is an enemy, if not it explodes, if so it gets that enemies UID and sets the health value of that specific enemy

The onClick sets a public variable with the ID of the selected enemy so later code can just find that enemy by that. (E.g. the border just simply gets activated if the UID == publicSelectedID)

Comment: So the obvious question then is: Does the island have a collider? If so how does the logic handle the ball entering a collider that does *not* belong to a ship? Is the logic turned off?

Comment: Yes the island has a collider, every time the ball collides with anything it checks basically if the colliders tag is enemy or not, if it is enemy execute code, if not explode the ball and try again. However the enemy code also ends in the ball exploding and I dont get any errors that could cause the code to stop executing

Comment: Have you verified that a collider can be hit while being within another collider?

Comment: Yes I verified that by going extremely close with my ship to the enemies ship so it is inside my player collider and enters the enemies collider.